# FastPDFKit builds for simulator but shows duplicate symbol error for arm7

Tags: ios, ipad

I've an ios app which is using FastPDFKit. It builds for simulator but shows duplicate symbol error for arm7

Any idea? I need help very quickly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:
Cleaning up the FastPdfKit target in FastPdfKit project and recompiled it. It generated a new framework. Grabbed the new .embeddedframework in the FastPdfKit project root directory. It works

Answer (score 0):

I add my solution, as if you follow the readme, it will ask you to add:

```
Inherit the project options: select the Project an from info tab and configurations line choose **FastPdfKitFramework** from the drop down list;
```

I remove the FastPdfKitFramework target to None and it work great now.
I hope it can be helpful for someone.

Comment: Thanks! It may help someone :)